# Xcode MapView selectAnnotation - but which one?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, annotations, android-mapview

Adding Annotations to a map like this

```
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" andSubTitle:@"Sub Title" andCoordinate:location];
[mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
[newAnnotation release];
```

A table on the left shows a list of restaurants. When clicked on one, "configureView" is being called, the map shall zoom to that Annotation and open the Annotation's popup.

```
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
[mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:xxx animated:YES];
```

How do I identify the specific Annotation ? What does the "xxx" have to be ?

Answer (score 0):

The 'xxx' should be a pointer to the annotation object. You're creating annotations that are separate from your data. That's fine, but it means that you'll have to do some extra work to keep track of the annotations and how they correspond to restaurants. Perhaps a more typical thing to do is to have your Restaurant class adopt the MKMapAnnotation. Then, when the user selects a restaurant in your table, you just have to figure out which restaurant they picked. Then you can:

```
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:theSelectedRestaurant animated:YES];
```

If you want to continue to keep the annotations separate, you might store them in a dictionary where the keys are restaurants, or perhaps some unique identifier that corresponds to each restaurant:

```
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:[annotationDict objectForKey:selectedRestaurant] animated:YES];
```

or:

```
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:[annotationDict objectForKey:selectedRestaurant.id] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. "theSelectedRestaurant" refers to the "title" parameter of the Annotation ?  Like, when I set my annotation with [point setCoordinate:(location)];
                [point setTitle:@"Some Name"];
                [point setSubtitle:@"hello"]; it should work with "[self.mapView selectAnnotation:@"Some Name" animated:YES];"  ?

Comment: No, not the title. It should be a pointer to an object that implements the MKAnnotation protocol. As I was trying to say, you can do this in your model objects, so that you can add them directly to the map.